# log4net - string matching on stack trace

Tags: .net, log4net, stack-trace

Outside of creating a custom filter, is there a way to add a filter on a log4net appender, such as the stringToMatch item, that searches for a certain string in the stack-trace? It seems that the current stringToMatch filter only matches on the message of the logged item, rather than the stack-trace.

I'm intending to send myself emails when exceptions are thrown that touch items in a certain library, and piggy-backing it onto the log4net stuff we already have seems like the best route to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by just creating my own custom filter that was basically a copy of the existing one, that filtered on the text of the stack-trace as well.